# Problems configuring the Tranxit driver app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-api-31

Well, I have a project developed in java and I want to emulate it using android stdio. I did all the firebase settings, downloaded the **google-services.json** file, configured the **build.gradle** file with the application id. I'm using **API 31** to emulate the application as specified in the configuration file (bluid.gradle) . I also linked a **SHA-1** key in the app.The compilation is successful, but when the application is opened in the emulator the following sentence appears- "New version available, please update the application to the new version to continue". I can't make progress in testing the app. Is it possible to remove this check? How should I do it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcqDT.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.